# Faulty running time from sp_WhoIsActive?

Tags: sql-server

Question 1:
If I turn on stored procedure sp_WhoIsActive v11.17 (2016-10-18)
on my VM, I get at "dd hh:mm:ss:mss" column value 02 06:34:12.000.

What does it mean?

I think that my request is not running 2 days.

[sp_whoisactive example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ1xn.png)

Question 2:
What means status: dormant?

Can you explain this status at context SQL SERVER statuses (suspended, runnable, running).

Comment: How do you know your query wasn't running for 2 days?  http://whoisactive.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

****Question-1:****

*What does "dd hh:mm:ss:mss" column mean in sp_whoisactive?*

**dd hh:mm:ss:mss:** It indicates the elapsed time of the process until it has been started.
For a sleeping session refers to the amount of time elapsed since login time.

****Question-2:****

**Can you explain this status at context SQL SERVER statuses (suspended, runnable, running).*

[Boost SQL Server Performance with Wait Statistics](https://www.sqlshack.com/boost-sql-server-performance-with-wait-statistics/)

> •  **Running** status indicates that the scheduled thread is currently
> being processed by the CPU.
>
> • **Suspended** status indicates that the assigned thread is waiting
> for a resource to be available. Such as, if any thread wants to access
> a data page that acquires an exclusive lock, it waits in the suspended
> status until the exclusive lock is removed and then it can access the
> page.
>
> • **Runnable** status indicates that the thread is not waiting for any
> resources, but the CPU still unable to process this task because it is
> dealing with another task.